# How do I add a document type to an XDocument?

Tags: c#, xml, doctype, linq-to-xml

I have an existing XDocument object that I would like to add an XML doctype to.  For example:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<a>test</a>");
```

I can create an XDocumentType using:

```
XDocumentType doctype = new XDocumentType("a", "-//TEST//", "test.dtd", "");
```

But how do I apply that to the existing XDocument?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can add an `XDocumentType` to an existing `XDocument`, but it must be the first element added. The documentation surrounding this is vague.

Thanks to Jeroen for pointing out the convenient approach of using `AddFirst` in the comments. This approach allows you to write the following code, which shows how to add the `XDocumentType` after the `XDocument` already has elements:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse("<a>test</a>");
var doctype = new XDocumentType("a", "-//TEST//", "test.dtd", "");
doc.AddFirst(doctype);
```

Alternately, you could use the `Add` method to add an `XDocumentType` to an existing `XDocument`, but the caveat is that no other element should exist since it has to be first.

```
XDocument xDocument = new XDocument();
XDocumentType documentType = new XDocumentType("Books", null, "Books.dtd", null);
xDocument.Add(documentType);
```

On the other hand, the following is invalid and would result in an InvalidOperationException: "This operation would create an incorrectly structured document."

```
xDocument.Add(new XElement("Books"));
xDocument.Add(documentType);  // invalid, element added before doctype
```

Comment: Does this also apply for XDocument? The MSDN link points to XmlDocument.

Comment: @dtb: it does, but I couldn't find it stated on MSDN for XDocument. Also see the updated code and InvalidOperationException.

Comment: You can add an XDocumentType later, but you have to make sure that it is the first element in the `XDocument`. You can do that by using `xDocument.AddFirst(documentType)` instead off `xDocument.Add(documentType)`.

Comment: @Jeroen thanks, that's much more convenient. I've updated my response to include this information.

Answer (score 3):

Just pass it to the [`XDocument` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352589.aspx) ([full example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299381.aspx)):

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XDocumentType("a", "-//TEST//", "test.dtd", ""),
    new XElement("a", "test")
);
```

or use [`XDocument.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.add.aspx) (the `XDocumentType` has to be added before the root element):

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument();
doc.Add(new XDocumentType("a", "-//TEST//", "test.dtd", ""));
doc.Add(XElement.Parse("<a>test</a>"));
```