# How to load an inline DTD for use with XDocument?

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml, dtd-parsing

I have a question regarding how to include a document type definition into an XML file, or from and XML file, that is being loaded into XDocument, in WP7. I have DTD file that is similar to this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE root [
 <!ELEMENT root (Person*)>

 <!ELEMENT Person (Name*, Description*)>
 <!ELEMENT Name (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT Description (#PCDATA)>

 <!ENTITY egrave "&#232;">
 <!ENTITY eacute "&#233;">
 <!ENTITY euro  "&#8364;">
]>
```

I need to add this DTD to the XML I'm getting to catch special characters, such as `&eacute;`.
I am getting the XML from the web to use in Linq using the following method:

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  string documentUrl = "http://www.example.com";

  WebClient client = new WebClient();

  client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);
  client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(documentUrl, UriKind.Absolute));
}

void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  Stream str = e.Result;

  XDocument data = XDocument.Load(str);

  // Saving the XML to the file system for later use
  IsolatedStorageFile isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
  IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("my.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, isoFile);
  StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(isoStream);
  XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(isoStream);

  data.Save(xw);

  // Creating a list to populate a listbox
  List<MyObject> list1 = new List<MyObject>();

  items = (from query in data.Descendants("Person")
    select new MyObject()
    {
    // Doing stuff here...
    }).ToList();

  listBox1.ItemsSource = items;

}
```

It seems that XDocument won't pass the XML if the DTD is put inline, i.e. in the actual XML itself.
I've tried many ways of using XDocumentType based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413053/how-do-i-add-a-document-type-to-an-xdocument) post, but I can't figure it out.
How can I do this?

Comment: MSDN do have WP7 specific forums: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/

Comment: Don't ask us to click over to the MSDN forums to read the question.  Ask it again, in full, with relevant code, here.

Answer (score 5):

You need to enable DTD processing when you read the XML document. To do that use a [`XmlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) with appropriate settings:

```
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings { DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse };
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(str, settings);
XDocument data = XDocument.Load(reader);
```

If you want to have the DTD external you need to specify a [`XmlResolver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlresolver.aspx) in the settings:

```
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
{
    DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse,
    XmlResolver = /* some resolver here */,
};
```

The default `XmlResolver` is an [`XmlUrlResolver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlurlresolver.aspx) which resolves URLs without using credentials. You may want to consider resolving the DTD from a local source instead. For that you can use a prepopulated [`XmlPreloadedResolver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.resolvers.xmlpreloadedresolver.aspx).

Comment: This makes sense and it doesn't matter if I do DTD inline. I tried this but I'm still getting errors, from the stack trace: Message=NotSupportedException
  StackTrace:
       at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDoctypeDecl()
       at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
       at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
       at System.Xml.Linq.XDeclaration..ctor(XmlReader r)
       at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options) <- As musch as I can fit in this comment.

Comment: Does that happen with both the inline and the external DTD? Hmm, I had the idea this was supported. I'll have to double-check tomorrow how we did that at work.

Comment: UPDATE: Remove inline DTD and include special characters = exception; Remove special characters and include inline DTD = exception; Remove inline DTD and remove special charactes = OK.